# Can you run an S3 API request with multiple prefixes?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I'm trying to set up logic that would target specific prefixes per user role. As follows:

Pack-user: Has access to everything in Pack bucket
Part-1: Only has access to part-1 prefix
Part-2: Only has access to part-2
...
Part-N: all the way up to N numbers

Basically, if a person doesn't have the pack, I'd have to specify every prefix they have access to to get all of the contents. Do I have to call multiple requests and then just append them? What's the common workflow for that? I'm new to AWS, so please forgive my ignorance. Thanks in advance!

**EDIT FOR CLARITY**
Something like this:

```
$iterator = $client->getIterator('ListObjects', array(
    'Bucket' => 'my-bucket'
), array(
    'limit'     => 999,
    'page_size' => 100,
    'prefix' => (this is where I want multiple prefixes to go)
));

foreach ($iterator as $object) {
    echo $object['Key'] . "\n";
}
```

Comment: Is each user actually an individual IAM user (with persistent credentials)? Or does each user simply assume an IAM role (and get temporary credentials)? And what is "the pack"?

Comment: a "Pack" in this instance is a group of files that are grouped with a prefix into a 'folder'

In this way, some users will have access to more than one pack, and some may have complete access and need all packs.

Bucket > Main Pack (The big group) > Pack 1, Pack 2, Pack 3...

So essentially, all packs from Main Pack on will have the prefix 'Main Pack'. Pack 1 and 2 and 3 are siblings and separate.

Basically allowing access to 'folders' from permissions. In this case the context doesn't mean anything. I just need to query multiple prefixes at a time. Is this possible?

Comment: I added the multi-line code to the OP for clarity. Thanks!

Comment: How many objects are we looking at? It sounds like your application is the authorizer in this case (S3 is not). You can't enumerate objects under multiple prefixes in a single API call. One option would be to maintain a separate index (e.g. in DynamoDB) that maps part numbers to S3 object keys.

Comment: Would I be able to just query the bucket numerous times then? Seems way less complicated to just grab the arrays and then merge to eliminate duplicates. Then I just have a master list to deal with.

I'm not quite sure of the exact limit, but I think the entire bucket (with all packs) will be close to 1000-2000 items (as I'll have gifs of videos for preview serving).

The benefit of multiple queries is I don't believe any query other than the master will fetch more than 1000 items.

Comment: Yes, you can query multiple prefixes by making multiple API calls, one prefix per query. That’s a given.

Comment: I apologize. The last half of my question was about how to merge the multiple queries. Are there any standard practices? I was either gonna append, or just do something multi-dimensional and iterate through them. If that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I completely understand what you're asking, but it sounds like this;

Each role is associated with a set of "packs"? Whatever a pack is. Some users have access to multiple "packs". When they use the AWS S3 API they should be able to see all the "packs" available to them.

First, I suggest using IAM roles/polices or bucket policies to manage this.

**IAM Role**

In the policy document attached to the group/user, provide the S3 commands they need, and add each bucket/folder as a resource. Then, when they try to use the API, they'll only see the results they're allowed to use

**BUCKET POLICY**

On each bucket/folder, use a policy that prevents anyone who doesn't belong to a certain role from using the resource. So each prefix would have a role, and the policy would only allow access to the role. Attach that role to a group then add users to that group.

**AWS S3 API**

If you can't use these options, there's also `aws s3 sync`

With sync you can use a combination of `--include` and `--exclude` files. First, exclude everything, in one file. Then give explicit buckets to include based on what that user needs. This is probably the most dynamic option and doesn't require permissions in the AWS account

**Use a Query**

You can also query based on some key values and then pipe that to the command you need. The query syntax docs are here: http://jmespath.org/specification.html#contains

```
aws s3api list-objects \
 --bucket $BUCKET_NAME \
 --query "Contents[?contains(Key, '$PREFIX') || contains(Key, '$PREFIX_2')].[Key]" \
 --output=text \
 | xargs -i sh -c "aws s3 cp s3://$BUCKET_NAME/{} ./{}"
```

Comment: I'm using the AWS SDK for PHP to make API requests to the bucket for a user, based on their role in the website. The website looks at the roles, and appends those corresponding roles to the prefixes (e.g. pack 1, etc).

Comment: I added the multi-line code to the OP for clarity. Thanks again!

Comment: Ok, so if the roles are added to the prefixes then you can use a policy to limit access yeah? So have you tried having the application assume the role before making the call and just removing the prefix? The only results returned from a list operation should be those it can see

Comment: Yes. I can communicate with the bucket. I just need a way to 'isolate' chunks of user-access content (so the server knows this user is only pack1, so only display 'pack1' prefix items.

Comment: Note that `--query` does not actually "query" anything.  This example reads the keys for every object in the whole bucket and strips out any results not matching the "query"... so this approach is slow and expensive.

Comment: My solution (edited in OP) is to make an API call via getIterator. I just realized I can only use one string prefix at a time. I guess I can just store each result in a variable and merge them, or create a multi-dimensional array to store to iterate through. Just thought it would be easier than that. No worries. Thanks for the input!